# AWS CodeDeploy - How To Reboot As Part Of Deployment Without CD Thinking It's An Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

I have a dependency in my CD deployment (.net fx) that requires a reboot of my windows server, but if I reboot from within one of the scripts during the deployment then CD thinks that the script has failed. I have also scoured the CD docs and cannot find anything in any of the hooks that allows or caters for a reboot.

I really hope I am just missing the obvious as I can imagine a lot of people would hit this, especially in the reboot-obsessed world of windows!

Can anyone help?